# Javascript function with dynamically generated arguments

Tags: javascript, html, function

Below code :

```
 loop(n times)
    create HTML Button Element
    count++;
    assign onclick event = function(){
                            openSomething("Value_"+count)
                            }
```

so if i create 3 input elements (n=3) and then go back click any of the three buttons then every time  openSomething("Value_"+3) only gets called.

**why  openSomething("Value_"+1) and openSomething("Value_"+2) does not get called?**

I am not sure what is going on may be it the scope issue but i dont know much about scope either, any help to push me in the right direction is much appreciated.

My original code

```
var count = 0;
   for(var i =0;i<someValue;i++){
        count++;               
        var button = document.createElement("img");
        button.src = "/images/small_button.gif";
        button.imageButton = true;
        button.srcBase = "/images/small_button";
        button.onclick = function () {
                       selectSomething("someIdText_"+count);};            
                       cell.appendChild(button);

    }
```

Comment: Show us your original code...

Comment: I think count are not getting updated by each click event call or have you define count in different function and passing that value to openSomething function?

Comment: @enyce12 Please take a look at original code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because JavaScript doesn't have block-level scoping of variables, and as a result everything is scoped to the function. That means that when you have code that uses a variable (like your loop counter `n` or your `count` variable) at a later point (i.e. after the full execution of the function), it will have its value set to the *last* value for the loop. You need to create a closure (a new scope for the variable) inside of your loop. Something like this (since you didn't post your actual code):

```
for(var i = 0, l = list.length; i < l; i++) {
    (function(count) {
        something.onclick = function() {
            openSomething("Value_" + count);
        }
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: Thank you but if i follow your suggestion when the element gets created and event is assigned it is running the function openSomething automatically which i do not want.

Comment: nevermind i found the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue

Answer (score 2):

For a more modern approtce use [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let),
works for firefox, chrome, and node

if you need to target all the browsers, use Anthony approach

```
for(var count = 0, l = list.length; count < l; count++) {
    let count;
    something.onclick = function() {
        openSomething("Value_" + count);
    }
}
```